# Rails background jobs without daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are interested in using a background job queue such as resque, backgroundjob or qu but due to CM restrictions we'd rather not have to start up external daemons as managers or workers on the queue.  A nice solution would be to have a rails app that can be deployed (we are using warbler and Tomcat) and have the background queue and workers run within Tomcat.  We'd also like to be able to choose a persistent backing store such as mongo or something that works with activerecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Mike Perhams [Girl Friday](https://github.com/mperham/girl_friday)

Its intended to be run via JRuby which it sounds like you already are so it might be perfect.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I forgot to mention that we'd like to be able to plug into our own database whether it be mongo or oracle and not dependent on something like reddis as it looks like this is.  Let me see if anything else comes in before accepting this answer.

Comment: girl_friday test have a mongo "driver" as backend storage. It's very easy to implement your own: https://github.com/mperham/girl_friday/blob/master/examples/backends/mongo_persistence.rb